# What is the zsh equivalent of "pushd -n" in bash?

Tags: zsh, cd-command, shell-builtin, pushd

I want to push a directory onto the directory stack in order to refer to it using "tilde shorthand" (eg. `~1` refers to the second entry in the directory list), but I don't want to actually switch to the directory. In bash, it seems this can be done using the `-n` flag to `pushd`.

What's the equivalent in zsh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the [`dirstack`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-dirstack) variable.

```
function insertd {
  emulate -L zsh
  typeset -i n=0
  while [[ $1 == [+-]<-> ]]; do
    n=$1
    shift
  done
  if (($# != 1)); then
    echo 1>&2 "Usage: insertd [+N|-N] DIR"
    return 3
  fi
  dirstack=($dirstack[1,$n] $1 $dirstack[$n,-1])
}
```

If you want to add this behavior to `pushd` itself, you can make it a function.

```
function pushd {
  if [[ $1 == -n ]]; then
    shift
    insertd "$@"
  else
    builtin pushd "$@"
  fi
}
```

This simple version does not treat combinations of `-n` and another option exactly like bash.

You can even [edit the variable](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-vared) directly.

```
vared dirstack
```

Comment: See also `array[n,0]=value` to insert an element before the nth one.

Answer (score 1):

You could always push it and then swap.

For example, `pushd -q ~/Downloads; pushd`